# getting error on server jquery.min.js:2 POST https://company.co.in/Home/tbl 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application.

One of my partial views is called through AJAX. When I execute the application on my local machine it works fine. But when I move it to the server it is throwing this error:

> POST https://company.co.in/Home/tbl 404 (Not Found).

i.e it is not able to the call the action method in the controller.

I used jQuery CDN from the web, then downloaded it and referenced it locally in my code, but the issue still persists

Controller code:

```
[AjaxChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult tbl(List<fer> val)
{
}
```

Client-side code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btncase", function (e) { 

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/Home/tbl",
        data:JSON.stringify(vals),
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype:"json",
        success:function(r){
        },
        failure: function(){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

Any ideas about how to resolve it will be appreciated.

Comment: 404 means your URL is wrong. We don't know what the correct URL is, it depends a bit on how you deployed the app, and what view the AJAX call is being made from. We can't see either of those things. If this $.ajax code is inside a cshtml view page then I suggest using the @Url.Action helper to let MVC build the URL correctly for you. If not then you'll need to work it out yourself. At a guess, try `Home/tbl` instead of `/Home/tbl` (so you have a URL relative to the current location, rather than the site root) - that can sometimes cause issues, depending on the IIS site's layout.

Comment: (BTW this has nothing to do with where you host your jQuery script file. I'm  not sure how you concluded that might be relevant).

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as below, Let framework to reslove your URL. Use @Url.Action("Controller","Action")

```
$(document).on("click", "#btncase", function (e) { 
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'@Url.Action("Home","tbl")',
        data:JSON.stringify(vals),
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype:"json",
        success:function(r){
        },
        failure: function(){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
```